# Counting and Excluding based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Basically I have the following in one table (only the first 25 rows) and I get it by doing this simple query.

```
select * from SampleDidYouBuy
order by MemberID, SampleID, DidYouBuy

SampleDidYouBuyID   SampleID    MemberID    DidYouBuy   DateAdded
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1217                23185       5           1           35:27.9
58458               23184       22          0           47:15.4
58459               23184       22          1           47:36.8
58457               23203       22          1           47:12.6
299576              23257       22          1           33:38.4
59470               23182       23          0           36:22.1
97656               23183       24          1           53:46.5
97677               23214       24          0           53:59.6
212732              23214       24          0           42:53.3
226583              23245       24          1           28:29.6
191718              23184       27          0           00:19.4
156363              23184       27          0           09:45.6
121106              23184       27          0           50:57.0
156362              23224       27          0           09:42.8
191716              23224       27          0           00:17.7
191715              23235       27          1           00:15.2
318100              23254       27          0           24:36.6
335410              23254       27          0           57:33.2
335409              23259       27          0           57:31.9
318099              23259       27          0           24:34.5
118989              23184       32          0           55:03.6
119013              23184       32          0           56:57.4
119842              23183       34          1           38:12.6
129364              23181       40          0           23:59.7
139977              23181       40          0           04:08.8
```

What I want to do is count the number Yes’s per member ID which I already know how to do **DidYouBuy = ‘1’**
But what I want to also do is count the number of No’s which is a bit trickier **‘DidYouBuy = 0’**

As you can see in the above table there are multiple entries for No’s for the same memberID and Sample ID (this is the ID of the sample they are marketing) and this is because that each time someone selects a No answer on the website, the question still remains and each time they click No it registers for that Sample. However when they click Yes the question disappears and there arent anymore No’s registered for that sample for that particular member.

I want to count the number of Unique No’s that **HAVE NOT** turned to a Yes. I know it sounds confusing, so when you got time give us a shout, I cant figure this out, is it using a condition statement?

I can get the Yes's without problems but to count the number of No's who have not selected Yes is a problem i cant figure out. I have a feeling it need to be done using the group by clause?

Expected Output

```
SampleDidYouBuyID   SampleID    MemberID    DidYouBuy   DateAdded
-----------------------------------------------------------------
59470       23182       23      0       36:22.1
212732      23214       24      0       42:53.3
121106      23184       27      0       50:57.0
191716      23224       27      0       00:17.7
335410      23254       27      0       57:33.2
318099      23259       27      0       24:34.5
119013      23184       32      0       56:57.4
139977      23181       40      0       04:08.8
```

This is what i would like it to look like when im querying for the No's, notice how the people who have a No but later answered yes are excluded from the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

```
select a.MemberId,
       count(distinct a.SampleId) as unique_nos
  from SampleDidYouBuy a
 where a.DIdYouBuy = 0
   and not exists (select 1 
                     from SampleDidYouBuy b
                    where b.MemberId = a.MemberId
                      and b.SampleId = a.SampleId
                      and b.DidYouBuy = 1)
 group by a.MemberId;
```

Demo at [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a6c7e/3).

To get rows with all columns,

```
select SampleDidYouBuyID, sampleid, MemberID, DIdYouBuy, DateAdded
  from SampleDidYouBuy a
 where a.DIdYouBuy = 0
   and not exists (select 1 
                     from SampleDidYouBuy b
                    where b.MemberId = a.MemberId
                     and b.SampleId = a.SampleId
                     and b.DidYouBuy = 1)
 group by memberid, sampleid
 order by MemberID,sampleid;
```

It is not quite clear from your expected output, which one of the duplicate rows should be showed.

Comment: Hi Ramblin' Man, I think that your query excludes wrongly the MemberId 32 -if I understand the user2771089 question-

Comment: Oops. Yes, the SampleId can be repeated for different members.

Comment: Hi @Ramblin' Man
When i use the above i get no results at all come up unfortunately

Comment: This looks a bit better i will have to check against my results, thank you!

Comment: @Ramblin' Man This is looking like the correct query, now all i need to do it tally up the results of the unique no's is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: @Ramblin' Man
Thank you for this
im just after the Tally, my expected Output was there just to show what i wanted to be able to count, if i can just tally up the total of unique_no's that would complete the answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simiplication of your problem is to count unique MemberId

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
   SELECT * FROM SampleDidYouBuy
   WHERE SampleID = {YourSampleID}
   GROUP BY MemberID
) AS sample;
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, as memberid can still be the same for other sampleID's in the table. I'm looking to count for each sampleID which also appears more than once depending on how many times the user selected No when they answer the question

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem then. Can you provide us with sample output that you want with reason why you come to that output.

Comment: @user2771089, I have updated the answer, but I don't know if it is what you want.

Comment: Hi @invisal

based off my above table i copied i would like it to look like this when i do a lookup for the No's

`
SampleDidYouBuyID SampleID MemberID DidYouBuy DateAdded
59470 23182 23 0 36:22.1
212732 23214 24 0 42:53.3
121106 23184 27 0 50:57.0
191716 23224 27 0 00:17.7
335410 23254 27 0 57:33.2
318099 23259 27 0 24:34.5
119013 23184 32 0 56:57.4
139977 23181 40 0 04:08.8
`,

Basically want the last answer that someone has chosen

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows expressions inside aggregation functions. Look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

So your SQL statement should be as follows (if I got your problem correctly?):

```
SELECT MemberID, COUNT(DidYouBuy=0) as 'No-s', COUNT(DidYouBuy=1) as 'Yes-s'
FROM SampleDidYouBuy
GROUP BY MemberID
```

If you wish to receive the number of No-s per sample:

```
SELECT SampleID, MemberID, COUNT(DidYouBuy=0)
FROM SampleDidYouBuy
GROUP BY SampleID, MemberID
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for this but unfortunately its not entirely correct. Basically the No's need to also exclude the people who have said Yes, if you look at the data table for the following data

58458   23184   22  0   47:15.4
58459   23184   22  1   47:36.8

You will see that member ID 22 answered no first for the sampleID 23184 then later on answered Yes. I need to exclude this No answer for this user in my look for the No's

hope thats a little clearer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you can try this query in order to find the number of Unique No’s that HAVE NOT turned to a Yes

Only For MemberID

```
SELECT 
  `MemberID`, COUNT(*) 
FROM `SampleDidYouBuy` 
GROUP BY `MemberID` 
HAVING MAX(`DidYouBuy`) = 0
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+
| MemberID | COUNT(*) |
+----------+----------+
|       23 |        1 |
|       32 |        2 |
|       40 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
```

For MemberID and sampleID

```
SELECT 
  `MemberID`, `sampleID`, COUNT(*) 
FROM `SampleDidYouBuy` 
GROUP BY `MemberID`, `sampleID` 
HAVING MAX(`DidYouBuy`) = 0
```

Output

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| MemberID | sampleID | COUNT(*) |
+----------+----------+----------+
|       23 |    23182 |        1 |
|       24 |    23214 |        2 |
|       27 |    23184 |        3 |
|       27 |    23224 |        2 |
|       27 |    23254 |        2 |
|       27 |    23259 |        2 |
|       32 |    23184 |        2 |
|       40 |    23181 |        2 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi Cristian thats exactly what im trying to do, i have tried your code but i get the following problem

    ``Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
    Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.``

Comment: Hi, I have included the output of my test. Can you share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE SampleDidYouBuy` probably your DidYouBuy field is a BIT type that not support MAX, MIN, SUM etc operators. My column is a tinyint(1) synonyms of BOOLEAN

Comment: Hi Cristian
I checked your output based off my initial output and its incorrect unfortunately since it doesnt exclude the the Yes's from the No's when it counts the No's if a Yes exists for the same sampleID and memberID

Comment: Can you share your "expected" output? :)

Comment: Sorry im just trying to figure out how to add in my expected output using the `code`, i will post it once i have it right

Comment: please see expected result table above

Answer (score 0):

try below query:-

```
select 
  (select count(MemberID) from SampleDidYouBuy where DidYouBuy='1' group by MemberID) as yesCount,
  (select count(MemberID) from SampleDidYouBuy where DidYouBuy='0' group by MemberID) as noCount 
from SampleDidYouBuy;
```